# How to replace characters before a number in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table FlightId with data like the following:

```
FlightId
-------
XXX158
DA245
KIKI1
UT298
GGG3
TTTT85
```

and I want to transform the data to:

```
FlightId
-------
DA158
DA245
DA001 <<
DA298
DA003 <<
DA085 <<
```

DA + Number must be between 001 and 999.

How can I do this?

Comment: This depends very much on the SQL dialect you use - is it MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQlite?

Comment: Reverting, casting to int, re-revert, pad, then concat. Approach for numbers >= 1000 would vary on how you'd like that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(FLightId LIKE 'DA%', 
            FlightId, 
            CONCAT('DA', LPAD(REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(FlightId) AS DECIMAL)), 3, '0'))) AS FlightId
FROM FlightTable
```

Casting the reversed field to a decimal is a trick to get rid of the non-numeric prefix. If a string starts with a number and then has non-numbers, converting it to a numeric type converts the numeric part and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat arcane way to do it in MySQL:

```
select concat('DA', lpad(reverse(reverse(FlightId) + 0), 4, '0'))
```

This reverses the original string and adds `0` to convert it to a number.  Then, `reverse()` this again to get the original number and pad it with zeros.